# ActionBar home button is misplaced in Nexus 5

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBar Sherlock with custom home button. In Nexus 5 home button is misplaced to the right side of the actionbar. You can see it from the images. Has anyone came up to this problem?

Thank you.

[image]

Other devices (Such as Nexus 4, Samsung Galaxy S4 etc.)

[image]

Nexus 5

For showing custom home button I'm am using

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `RelativeLayout` for my custom view and I think it was causing the problem I had. I switched it with `LinearLayout` and set some properties and my problem solved. These properties are

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

But still I didn't understand why it works well with other devices such as Samsung Galaxy S4, Nexus 4 etc. and not working well with Nexus 5 and Nexus 7.

Before I switched to `LinearLayout` I tried various way to solve my problem including control for devices and settings margins programmatically.

For those still insist using `RelativeLayout` for ActionBarSherlock customView you can use the workaround which I do not recommend.

```
if (Build.MODEL.contains("Nexus 5")) {
      LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      params.setMargins(-150, 0, 0, 0);
      actionBar.setCustomView(v, params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Hope, you have added below lines

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

### ActionBar Sherlock is depreciated change it with appcompart

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work. Try

```
    View homeIcon = findViewById(android.R.id.home);
    ((View) homeIcon.getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
```