# Android Custom Actin Bar Miss Space issue?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am getting same problem like this [ActionBar home button is misplaced in Nexus 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23311240/actionbar-home-button-is-misplaced-in-nexus-5)

i solve the issue only for nexus 5. but i am unsuccessful to get global solution for this because this issue not happening only in nexus 5 , i am also facing this problem in moto g, moto e etc etc.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.